# ASP.NET VB File download from table link

Tags: asp.net, download

I have a populated table from a database in my VB ASP.NET application, like so:

```
<dl class="row">
    <dd style="width:20%; background:none;">
        <%# Eval("name")%>
    </dd>
    <dd style="width:20%;">
        <%# Eval("description")%>
    </dd>
    <dd style="width:30%;">
        <a href="<%# Eval("templateLink")%>"><%# Eval("templateId")%></a>
    </dd>
</dl>
```

Now, I have saved link to the template in `templateLink` and I'm using `Guid` as it's name, namely `templateId`.
Now, when I click that link I want to be able to save the file, but now it does not do that. I can't even access the file on server (on dev environment I can access but still can't download).

This is the path I'm using.

```
<configuration>
    <appSettings>
        <add key="UploadLocation" value="C:\inetpub\wwwroot\MyProject\Intranet\Resources\"/>
    </appSettings>
<configuration>
```

And this is the upload code:

```
Dim TempEx As String = System.IO.Path.GetExtension(fuTemp.FileName)
Dim TempPath As String = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings("UploadLocation")
Dim TempName As String = report.TempID.ToString + TempEx

fuTemp.PostedFile.SaveAs(TempPath + TempName)

report.TemplateLink = TempPath + TempName
```

As you can see, I'm saving the path to TemplateLink which I'm using later to create the `a href` for the table. I tried using several solutions I've found around the web but couldn't make much use of it.

If possible please clarify this problem to me :(

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll want to store `UploadLocation` as a relative path:

`<add key="UploadLocation" value="/Intranet/Resources/"/>`

In your upload code, use `Server.MapPath(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings("UploadLocation")` to get the filesystem path.

Then binding `TempPath + TempName` should give you a proper HTTP link rather than a filesystem path.

Comment: Tried that also. Same thing happened.

Comment: To be more precise, I used the relative path like this: `"~/Intranet/Resources/"`. And it pointed properly to the same file, but it returned the filesystem path, same as the previous.

Comment: Omit the '~'. And so you're using `fuTemp.PostedFile.SaveAs(Server.MapPath(TempPath) + TempName)` and `report.TemplateLink = TempPath + TempName` respectively? and NOT using `Server.MapPath` when setting the value of `TempPath`?

Comment: yeah I've found the issue at hand and fixed it... Thanks a lot. It was missing `Server.MapPath`... Silly mistakes people make in a hurry...